# Dialogflow SDK returning Tried calling: [](“queryText”) error

Tags: flutter

**dailogflow work fine in its website but when I send hi on flutter it shows null response:**

```
  [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
  Receiver: null
  Tried calling: []("queryText")
```

Comment: SAME FOR ME ANY SOLUTION?